# How to select region for AWS Codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am configuring an AWS Codepipeline with an AWS Codecommit Repository and an S3 bucket. I am running into trouble creating my Codepipeline and receiving the following error:

`An error occurred while validating the artifact bucket 'artifact-bucket-name': The bucket named artifact-bucket-name is not located in the us-east-1 AWS region. Choose a valid artifact bucket in 'us-east-1', or create a new artifact bucket to use in your pipeline.`

My question is how do I change the region for the pipeline I am creating to US-West-2? I don't see any option for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS CodePipeline (CP) will be created in your current region that you use. There is no special region selection only for CP.

Therefore, before you create your CP make sure to change AWS console to the region you require:

[image]

Comment: @nflauria No problem.